# how to change the input box color while using form property in shell script using dialog

Tags: shell-script, shell, dialog, whiptail

[image]

how to change the input box color while using form property in shell script using dialog

Answer (score 0):

The [manpage](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-RUN-TIME-CONFIGURATION) does not go into detail, but mentions [*configuration files*](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-RUN-TIME-CONFIGURATION).  The sample configuration files in the sources use named configuration items, e.g., this chunk from [`sourcemage.rc`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/e58f01efc4c91cb9891e0411024c59149ffda43c/samples/sourcemage.rc#L63):

```
# Input box color
inputbox_color = dialog_color

# Input box border color
inputbox_border_color = dialog_color
```

The *values* are either referencing previously-set ones, such as [`dialog_color`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/e58f01efc4c91cb9891e0411024c59149ffda43c/samples/sourcemage.rc#L36):

```
# Dialog box color
dialog_color = (BLACK,WHITE,OFF)
```

or, as shown, referencing curses color-names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will you please advice where we need to insert the code exactly (Use \Zn\Z4Up\Zn/\Zn\Z4Down\Zn keys to navigate to next field. Press \ZnTab \Zn to jump to \Zn\Z4OK\Zn/\Zn\Z4Cancel\Zn buttons) " \
20 75 0 \
        "IP Address:"     1 1   "$ipaddress"    1 25 48 0 \
        "Subnet Mask:"    3 1   "$subnetmask"   3 25 48 0 \
        "Gateway:"        5 1   "$gateway"      5 25 48 0 \
       2>&1 1>&3)